# In Rich Text Editor Special Character are getting stored as Special Character not as their HTML code

Tags: html, special-characters, aem, rich-text-editor, inserthtml

We are using the Rich Text Editor in CQ, with special characters.

Whenever we add special characters by our button in the RTE, the character is added but is saved as the character in the source too, rather than the encoded HTML entity.

We are calling:

```
doc.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, htmlToInsert);
```

In `htmlToInsert`, we are sending the HTML code value of special character like `&#165;` for yen, but it is saving ¥ for yen, not `&#165;`.

We need to store HTML code values only. Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a literal character in an HTML document. It's generally preferred as it uses (marginally) less bandwidth / storage space and is easier to understand when looking at the source code. Why do you want to use the character reference? And what are you defining as "special" (anything that isn't ASCII? Anything that isn't a letter or a number? Anything that isn't a `&`, `#`, or a number?)?

Comment: we want character reference since we have to send the this HTML code to some other Business team which want it as a character reference.
Special Means- symbol like Registered(&#174;),copyright(&#169;),degree(&#176;), tick (&#10003;) Yen ("&#165;"), and other like this .

We can add character in RTE by misctoolplugin's feature "specialchars"(by this functionality user can add character at cursor position) So I am talking of that Functionality of RTE.
I hope you get now.